# meta in HTML run a hard refresh

Tags: html, meta

I created a HTML file to obtain a file that will update data every 1 minute.

I had tried `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">` function but it doesn't show the latest data.

If I press CTRL + F5 manually, the page will update the latest data.

How do I perform a Hard Refresh instead of normal refresh in HTML by using `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">` .

Comment: Please put your Update as the accepted answer

Comment: Noted, will accept my own answer after 2 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

I found the issue, is it because my source file(xml file) is getting the same data.

After I change the
`xmlhttp.open("GET", "merged_.xml, true);` to

`xmlhttp.open("GET", "merged_.xml?id="+Math.random(), true);`

The source file will update to the latest data.

**Reference**: https://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/4283873.htm

Answer (score 0):

it's not accurate but it's difficult with html alone.

i think you should try using javascript

```
<script>
    var current = new Date();
    future.setSeconds(0);
   ...
...
    setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(true); }, timeout);
</script>
```